# App indicators in Gnome are disappearing

Tags: 18.04, indicator, gnome-shell

App indicators of gnome are disappearing after lock screen. When I unlock the screen, indicators are not there anymore. If I restart gnome using ALT+F2+r, indicator appear again. To be clear, indicators are missing after logging in, obviously they are not shown in the lock screen as expected.

[image: indicator shown correctly]

[image: indicators missing]

I've tried installing `TopIcons plus` extension and tried enabling/disabling `Ubuntu appindicators` extension, but no difference.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same "fail", even the lock screen doesn't work (I can't change the option in settings, it looks like I cannot change none of this). Maybe it's for an update. The only way is like you said, restarting Gnome or even the Ubuntu Appindicator, but you need start (K)Status (but the next session you need to do the same, off (K)Status and activate Ubuntu Appindicator if u want work this).

Comment: I didn't get exactly what you mean but I've installed `(k)statusnotifieritem/appindicator support` extension. That fixed most of the problem except when I restart ubuntu, indicators are not visible after first login. Disabling and enabling this plugin in gnome-tweaks helps (which is faster than restarting gnome).

Comment: After using this for a while, I still have problems like all indicators are disappearing (sometimes only restart helps), new indicators doesn't show up (when a new app is started).